# Error when resolving ILogger in Console application

Tags: exception, unity-container, registration, serilog

I can't resolve ILogger instance in my console application...

I'm using Unity IoC and Serilog.

The registration is done like this:

```
container = new UnityContainer();    
container.RegisterFactory<ILogger>(factory =>
{
    ILogger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger();

    return log;
}, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

And then when I try this:

```
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

I get an exception:

> Unity.ResolutionFailedException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Failed
>   to select a constructor for Serilog.Core.Logger
>   _____________________________________________________ Exception occurred while:
>
> •resolving type:  'ILogger' mapped to 'Logger'
>
> Source=Unity.Container   StackTrace:    at
>   Unity.UnityContainer.ExecuteValidatingPlan(BuilderContext& context)
>   at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type,
>   String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides)    at
>   Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container,
>   ResolverOverride[] overrides) 
>   Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Failed to select a
>   constructor for Serilog.Core.Logger
>
> Inner Exception 2: InvalidRegistrationException: Exception of type
>   'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown.

I even tried registering it like this:

```
container = new UnityContainer();

ILogger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(log);
```

but with the same resulting exception thrown.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem...
The problem was this line of code down the road, overriding my configuration:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);
```